# System.ObjectDisposedException occurs, When running Unit Test in ABP framework

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, xunit

I meet a exception "System.ObjectDisposedException " when I'm running the Unit Test.

In the application layer, the code is as follows.

```
//Interface definition
public interface IAnalysisDataQuerier{
   DataTable GetDataTableWithQueryCondition(int windmillId, int partsId, int[] analysisItemIds, DateTime? starTime, DateTime? endTime);
}
```

Next, I implement the interface as below, where I use the Dependency Injection method(Castle Windsor) to initialize the IbCollectionInfo repository.

```
    //Implement 
    public class AnalysisDataQuerier : IAnalysisDataQuerier, ITransientDependency
    {
... ...
private readonly IRepository<IbCollectionInfo> _ibCollectionInfoRepository;
public AnalysisDataQuerier(
            IRepository<IbCollectionInfo> ibCollectionInfoRepository)
    {
        _ibCollectionInfoRepository = ibCollectionInfoRepository;
     }
    ... ...
        public DataTable GetDataTableWithQueryCondition(int windmillId, int partsId, int[] analysisItemIds, DateTime? starTime, DateTime? endTime)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //Error happens at the below codes.
            var collectionInfoList = _ibCollectionInfoRepository.GetAll()
                            .WhereIf(starTime != null, a => a.CollectionDate >= starTime)
                            .WhereIf(endTime != null, a => a.CollectionDate <= endTime)
                            .Where(a => a.BiWindmillInfoId.Equals(windmillId) && a.BiWindmillPartsInfoId.Equals(partsId)).ToList();
            ......
        }
    }
```

Then I design a test code in my Test project as below.

```
 public class TestQueryImportedExcelData: AppTestBase
    {
        private readonly IAnalysisDataQuerier _analysisDataQuerier;

        public TestQueryImportedExcelData()
        {
            _analysisDataQuerier = Resolve<IAnalysisDataQuerier>();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void TestQueryFunction()
        {
             DataTable dt = _analysisDataQuerier.GetDataTableWithQueryCondition(2, 1, new[] {3,4,5,8,1003,1004},null,null);

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                ... ...
            }
        }

    }
```

And then, I run the above Unit Test, the error happens in my implementation codes.

```
 var collectionInfoList = _ibCollectionInfoRepository.GetAll()
```

The error message is as follows.

> System.ObjectDisposedException:“Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved
>   from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same
>   context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you
>   are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a
>   using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let
>   the dependency injection container take care of disposing context
>   instances.”

The stacktrace message is:

> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.CheckDisposed()
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TEntity>.GetEnumerator()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.ToList()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>   at ... ...

I'm sure that there is not async method in my code. 
So, could you give me a solution to dismiss the problem.

Comment: Which line of code throws the exception?

Comment: This line " var collectionInfoList = _ibCollectionInfoRepository.GetAll()"

Comment: @mingalex you have not shown where `_ibCollectionInfoRepository` comes from in the method under test, which makes the question difficult to understand as it is incomplete. Provide a [mcve] that would help make the problem more understandable.

Comment: Okay, I've added some codes and notes in my question. @Nkosi

Comment: Sigh...this is clearly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but since there are way too many factors missing those tryingto help you are left with only guesses. I suggest you review the `Resolve<IAnalysisDataQuerier>();` because that is responsible for getting the SUT and injecting its dependencies.

Comment: Oh. Because of using the ABP framework, i.e. https://aspnetboilerplate.com, I didn't know the details implementing the DI. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fine...I've known the key of this problem, due to the ABP framework manages database connections and transactions by using its unit of work system and does all of this automatically if a class inherited the default ****AppServiceBase class in domain layer or application layer.

Because my class did not inherit the ****AppServiceBase class, I should explicitly append the UnitOfWork attribute to my function as below.

```
[UnitOfWork]
public DataTable GetDataTableWithQueryCondition(int windmillId, ...)
```

It works without the System.ObjectDisposedException exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can try *WithUnitOfWorkAsync* in unit tests. See snippet below from the Mastering ABP Framework book:

> If you try to run this test, you will see it throws an exception (of
> type ObjectDisposedException) because the GetQueryableAsync method
> requires an active unit of work (UoW) (see the Understanding the UoW
> system section of Chapter 6, Working with the Data Access
> Infrastructure, to remember ABP's UoW system). The base test class
> provides the WithUnitOfWorkAsync method to execute code in a UoW, so
> we can fix the test code as shown in the following code block:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Test_Querying_With_Uow()
{
   await WithUnitOfWorkAsync(async () =>
   {
      var queryable =
         await _repository.GetQueryableAsync();
      var exists = await queryable.Where(
         x => x.EventId ==
              _testData.AbpMicroservicesFutureEventId &&
              x.UserId == _testData.UserJohnId
      ).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
      exists.ShouldBeNull();
    });
}
```